# If Then Else broke my script

Tags: windows, powershell, scheduled-tasks

Currently I have this code -

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted
$name = (Get-WmiObject win32_bios).SerialNumber.Trim()
$oldname = (Get-WmiObject win32_computersystem).Name.Trim()
IF ($oldname -eq $name){Exit}
Else{ Rename-computer -ComputerName $oldname  -NewName "$name" -force
Start-Sleep -s 5

Restart-Computer}
```

And I have it set to run as a scheduled task at logon and without the If Else it works perfectly however I don't want it to run every time a user logs in because it will just be a cycle of rebooting.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you only want it to run once, why not add a SCHTASKS command to at the end of the script to delete or disable the task?

Comment: what error are you receiving?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest some changes:

1. `Set-ExecutionPolicy` is unnecessary, because if the machine has started processing the script, then the executionpolicy isn't a problem. So remove that, and specify it in the `powershell.exe`-call instead, like: `powershell.exe -executionpolicy unrestricted`
2. Use `if($oldname -ne $name) { rename-computer .... }` so you can remove the else part. Much cleaner

Try running the modified script below, and report back with the output in the `scriptlog.txt`-file.

```
$logpath = "c:\scriptlog.txt"

$name = (Get-WmiObject win32_bios).SerialNumber.Trim()
$oldname = (Get-WmiObject win32_computersystem).Name.Trim()

"NewName is '$name'" | Out-File $logpath -Append
"OldName is '$oldname'" | Out-File $logpath -Append

IF ($oldname -ne $name){
    "If-test TRUE" | Out-File $logpath -Append

    Rename-computer -ComputerName $oldname  -NewName $name -Force
    Start-Sleep -s 5

    Restart-Computer
} else { #I've added the else-part just because of logging.
    "IF-test FALSE" | Out-File $logpath -Append
}
```

Comment: I will try this right now.  Thank you for the quick response.

Comment: It works perfectly, thank you for your help.  I have been working on this for a while and this is exactly what I needed.  Thank you thank you thank you.